# Error MSB4057 in Microsoft.Common.targets

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

I wrongly edit and save the file

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets

and now I can't compile anymore.
The error I got is

> 1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets(767,39):
>   error MSB4057: The target "_Xsd" does not exist in the project.

I reinstalled Visual Studio 2010, I copied the file from another computer but nothing works and I still have the same error. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search the solution on Internet and i found:

1. Copy the right target file from another machine to replace the target file.
2. Uninstall and re-install .Net Framework 4.0 and check if it works.

I tried to restore or install new version of the .NET framework, but other problems occured during installation maybe dued also by hardware problems (i got blue screen sometimes).
I know it isn't a good solution, but at the moment I solved the issue by formatting and reinstalling everything.